# Adding Style Tag in Vue Component Throw Error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I am learning vue first time and developing a SPA (admin part) with `laravel 5.7` and `vue router`.

I am using laravel mix to compile my `.vue` files.

If I add `<style>` tag in my component file, it redirect me to to root url and throw some error (seen in browser inspector tool)

I re installed all the `npm` packages but it didn't worked

My sample component file (`blog.vue`)

```
<template>
   <div>
      <h2 class="title">Create Blog</h2>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .title {
      color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Below is `package.json` in laravel root direcotry

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.26",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
        "vue2-transitions": "^0.3.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue-sweetalert2": "^2.1.1"
    }
}
```

I was expecting it to display the page without any problem but I got following output in browser console

```
TypeError: "modules[moduleId] is undefined"
    __webpack_require__ http://laravelvue.local/js/app.js:64
    ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/components/ListCategories.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& http://laravelvue.local/2.js:93
    __webpack_require__ http://laravelvue.local/js/app.js:64
    ./node_modules/style-loader/index.js!./node_modules/css-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/components/ListCategories.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& http://laravelvue.local/2.js:113
    __webpack_require__ http://laravelvue.local/js/app.js:64
    ./resources/js/components/ListCategories.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& http://laravelvue.local/2.js:289
    __webpack_require__ http://laravelvue.local/js/app.js:64
    vue http://bestreviews.local/2.js:238
    __webpack_require__ http://laravelvue.local/js/app.js:64
app.js:54748:17
```

**Note:** http://laravelvue.local/ is my local development url on my Windows 10 machine, PHP 7.1, MySQL 5.6

**EDIT:** adding content of Laravel's app.js as asked by @Kyuriko

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './components/App';

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';

import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);

import router from './router'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    components: {App}
});
```

Content of `webpack.mix.js`

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/admin/css/style.css');
```

Also, the content of `bootstrap.js`

```
window._ = require('lodash');

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Note: Comments are removed

Comment: Can you post the contents of Laravel's app.js (js/app.js)? And your webpack.mix.js

Comment: Added the content of `webpack.mix.js` as well

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this is a known issue. The suggested _workarounds_ are 1) downgrading to Laravel Mix 3.0 or 2) import a blank scss file into your app.js to force style-loader and css loader to be included in the bundle - see [https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2064#issuecomment-511364566](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2064#issuecomment-511364566)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the provided solution

Comment: Great, I followed the chris-rodgers work around as pointed by you and It worked.
I think for proper solution we have to wait.

Comment: The error is gone, but I still don't see thy applyed styles ...